# slash command discord permission

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to have a slash command that only admin can use but I can't find the option for this purpose

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [
    
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('setting').setDescription('Replies with the setting!').setDefaultPermission(false)
    
    .addSubcommand(subcommand => subcommand.setName('log').setDescription('Select a user')
        .addChannelOption(option => option.setName('log-channel').setDescription('Select a channel'))
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('delete-log').setDescription('Delete log channel'))), 
]
   .map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

This is my slash command when I'am using this code the command is locked so this is good for when the user is not an admin
[image]

But I want the command to be unlucked when the user as the permission admin like so

[image]

So I was wondering if I could set the permission for the command like this

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [
    
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('setting').setDescription('Replies with the setting!').setDefaultPermission(false).setPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')
    
    .addSubcommand(subcommand => subcommand.setName('log').setDescription('Select a user')
        .addChannelOption(option => option.setName('log-channel').setDescription('Select a channel'))
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('delete-log').setDescription('Delete log channel'))), 
]
   .map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-command-permissions.html#role-permissions),

> ```
> const permissions = [
>   {
>       id: '464464090157416448',
>       type: 'ROLE',
>       permission: false,
>   },
> ];
>
> await command.permissions.add({ permissions });
> ```